# Is openlayers 3 feature animation only triggered by postcompose?

Tags: animation, openlayers-3

I am animating points in OpenLayers 3. The points are coming from a large dataset. Currently, my animation is triggered as a callback once the geoJSON data is loaded. I would like to use OpenLayers feature animation using frameState and vectorContext and have been running experiments only to conclude that to use this scheme I need to trigger it using the postcompose event. Is there a way to trigger it as a callback once my large geoJSON files have loaded?

Thanks.

Comment: Is it missing anything to finish this question?

Comment: My apologies, I was delayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**: Take a look at this example - http://openlayers.org/en/v3.11.0/examples/feature-move-animation.html.

---

The way to trigger a `postcompose` event is [`map.render()`](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.10.0/apidoc/ol.Map.html#render); Now if you want to wait until you `geojson` is fully loaded check for its [`state`](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.10.0/apidoc/ol.source.Vector.html#getState):

```
vectorSource.on('change', function(evt){
    if (vectorSource.getState() === 'ready') {
        //fully loaded
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Jonatas. Can I also use button events, such as a "play" and "pause" button?

Comment: For sure, I've submitted an example ([#4291](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/pull/4291)) and you can [see here](https://github.com/jonataswalker/ol3/blob/feature-move-example/examples/feature-move-animation.js) the code.